# Database Insertion Fails Because Of Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I'm working on database migration program and I'm trying to migrate one database to the another database whoose tables are already created. To be more specific I have two database with almost same tables and the one is full and the other one is empty. My problem is migration table values is proccessing alphabeticly. Some tables have foreign key and if these tables are come before alphabeticly from foreign key tables ,I cannot inser values. Is there any way to disable foreign key check on java or postgresql. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am right, there is no possibility to disable fk on postgresql. As @mcfinnigan said, you can drop fk before starting insertion or you can recreate contraints with DEFERRABLE key. Refer to [postgresql CREATE TABLE documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-createtable.html)

DEFFERABLE means, fk will not be checked until transaction finished.

Comment: Is there any update statement that can set table deferrable ?

Comment: You can not modify a constraint on table. only you can add or drop with alter table statement. ALTER TABLE xxx ADD CONSTRAINT fk_xxx [...] or ALTER TABLE xxx DROP CONSTRAINT fk_xxx . You must recreate table with giving DEFFERABLE key to contraint definition. Then you should call "SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED" if you create contraint with DEFFERABLE key.

Answer (score 2):

Referential integrity is a DB property, not a JDBC property - you will need to explicitly drop or disable the FK constraints on the database before running your import, then reenable them afterwards.

It might be a better idea to determine the hierarchical structure of your data and insert data starting with the independent records first, then link the dependent records to these during insert.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the first one. Second one can be so complex.